# How can a perl module find its own path?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm creating my own module, lets call it `X::Y`. Of course, the module will be in the file `X/Y.pm`.

Lets say `Y` needs to call an external program, `prog`. Ideally I'd just like to put `prog` in `X`, so I can run `X/prog`. I'd like to not have hardcode `X/prog`s full path, and for the module to work regardless of the current working directory set.

How can I find the full path of a module from inside a module? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The full path to the source file currently being executed is supplied by Perl's [`__FILE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) special literal.

However I would prefer to see the external program installed where it would normally be, and the path there either coded as a constant in the Perl code or included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

Borodin answered the question but some related information:

[FindBin](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin) - finds the directory that the script was run from (use within the script itself or within a package loaded by it)

[Neil Bower's CPAN modules for getting a module's path](http://neilb.org/reviews/module-path.html) - detailed review of modules for finding another module's path.

Answer (score 0):

Once a module is loaded, it's path is in the global `%INC` variable. To look it up, you need to do a simple conversion:

1. change `::` in the package name to `/`
2. append `.pm`

So to find the location of the module `X::Y`, you would look in `$INC{"X/Y.pm"}`.